# Download .msg file to client server

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, client, response

I am trying to download a file from the server to a folder that the client on click even but I can't handle the logic
I try physically so physically path is perfectly working

For example the DownloadLocation could be C:/myfolder

Code:

```
if (e.CommandName == "SendDraft")
{

  int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

  string JROPID = gvReleaseOrderEmail.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text.Trim();
  string ReleaseOrderNo = gvReleaseOrderEmail.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text.Trim();

  DataTable Report = Utilities.GetDataTable2("exec SP_JobEstReleaseOrderPress '" + Session["Compcode"].ToString().Trim() + "','" + JROPID.Trim() + "'");
  ReportDocument crystalReport;
  crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
  crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~\Modules\JobOrder\Reports\JobEstReleaseOrderPress.rpt"));
  crystalReport.SetDataSource(Report);
  DataRow dr = Report.Rows[0];

  ExportOptions exportOptions = new ExportOptions();
  DiskFileDestinationOptions diskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
  string pdfFilePath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Modules/JobOrder/Reports/" + ReleaseOrderNo.Trim() + ".pdf");
  diskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = pdfFilePath;
  exportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
  exportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
  exportOptions.ExportDestinationOptions = diskFileDestinationOptions;
  crystalReport.Export(exportOptions);


  crystalReport.Close();
  crystalReport.Dispose();


  string toEmail = gvReleaseOrderEmail.Rows[index].Cells[9].Text.Trim(); // Assuming Email field is at index 8
  string subject = dr["EmailSubject"].ToString();
  string Body = dr["Body"].ToString();
  string ccEmail = dr["cc"].ToString();
  string attachmentPath = pdfFilePath; // Path to your attachment file


  try
  {
      var senders = new Sender("Nadeem", dr["MailFrom"].ToString());
      var msg = new Email(senders, subject);

      msg.Recipients.AddTo(toEmail, "Recipient Name");
      msg.Recipients.AddCc(ccEmail, "CC Recipient Name");
      msg.Subject = subject;
      msg.BodyHtml = Body;
      msg.Attachments.Add(attachmentPath);

      //This is physically path download perfectly on this path
      string msgFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Modules/JobOrder/Reports//" + ReleaseOrderNo.ToString().Trim() + ".msg");

      if (File.Exists(msgFilePath))
      {
          File.Delete(msgFilePath);
      }


      msg.Save(msgFilePath);

      msg.Dispose();


      if (File.Exists(attachmentPath))
      {
          File.Delete(attachmentPath);
      }

      // Set up the response for file download
      byte[] buffer;
      using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(msgFilePath, FileMode.Open))
      {
          int fileSize = (int)fileStream.Length;
          buffer = new byte[fileSize];
          fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, fileSize);
      }

      // Set up the response for file download
      Response.Clear();
      Response.Buffer = true;
      Response.BufferOutput = true;
      Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-outlook"; // Content type for .msg files
      Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "msgFilePath.msg"); // Specify the filename
      Response.CacheControl = "public";
      Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
      Response.End();

  }
  catch (System.Exception ex)
  {
      Logger.LogError("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);

  }
}
```

Comment: _"Please guide me how can i fix this issue"_ - _What_ issue? You haven't stated what it is that is _not_ working as expected.

Comment: File not download on download folder in client server

Comment: I want to download .msg file on client server when user click and event

Comment: You cannot force a download to a specific folder on a client computer. You can only serve the download and that's it.

Comment: You should also consider constructing paths in a OS-agnostic manner, but that's not going to solve your problem. I am currently wondering if the intermediate step of writing to disc is really necessary. Also: be aware that you currently set the content filename explicitly to (literally) "msgFilePath.msg". I am guessing that's not what you intend it to be.

Comment: When you download a file in general you can't set nor choose the path (location) on my computer. This is a security risk since then you could download dangerous files into my windows folder or overwrite files on my computer.  Thus most browsers ignore path and files go into download folder based on users browser settings and web sites can't change or even mess or even know what folders I have.  So no, you can't screw around with my computer and if you could then no one would ever use the internet.  Only users can choose download location not server

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Web Forms, then the simplest approach would be to hand the file over to the browser via the Response object, and let the user decide where to save it. The code example below is how I specifically handle downloading a .MSG file.

```
using (SqlDataReader rd = cm.ExecuteReader()){
Response.Clear();
while (rd.Read())
{
    if (rd["ContentType"].ToString().ToLower() == AttachmentsAndUploads.ContentType_Office_MSG)// Outlook
{
    Response.ContentType = rd["ContentType"].ToString();
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment;filename={rd["FileName"].ToString()}");// .msg
        Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])rd["FileData"]);
    }
}
```

}